# Access instance variables in one class from another class

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am working with spring boot to make a rest api and I have these two classes, Material and Warehouse. In Material class I have defined these instance variables:

```
@Id
@NotBlank(message="Id cannot be blank")
private String materialId;
private String materialGroup;
private String materialCode;
private String materialType;
private String materialDimension;
private String materialDescription;
private String status;
private LocalDate creationDate= LocalDate.now();
private LocalDate updateDate = LocalDate.now();
private List<Material> materials;
private Map<warehouseCode, Quantity> warehouse;
//getters and setters
```

In Warehouse class I have defined the following variables:

```
private String warehouseCode;
private String warehouseName;
private String status;
private HierarchyNode operationalArea;
private Address address;
private LocalDate creationDate = LocalDate.now();
private LocalDate updateDate = LocalDate.now();
//getters and setters
```

Here is also my Quantity class that is also being referred to back at **Map** in the Material class.

```
private int quantity;
```

Here is my MaterialRepositoryClass:

```
public interface MaterialRepository extends MongoRepository<Material,String>,QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Material>{

    List<Material> findByCode(String materialCode);

}
```

And here is my MaterialController class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/material")
@CrossOrigin
public class MaterialController {

@Autowired
private MaterialService materialService;

@PostMapping
public TukioResponse addNewMaterials(@RequestBody Material material) {
    return materialService.addOrEditMaterial(material);
}
```

I want to access the instanceVariable **warehouseCode** inside the **Map** found in the Material class. The material class here is the super class in my case. I'd also like a demonstration of how the Map variable would look like in the body of a post request in postman. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use the instance variable warehouseCode in the Warehouse class as a key in the Map in Material class?

Comment: yes i am, have any ideas?

Comment: Since warehouse code is a String, you should declare the Map as Map<String, Quantity>, not use the property name. Also, you mentioned the Material class is a super class. What are the child classes? and where do you create instances of them?

Comment: Found the solution, thanks